Creating valid XML with xmlstarlet
I want to use xmlstarlet to select some records of a gigantic .xml file. My problem is, that I need the output to be valid XML.
Minimal example:
using xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//record[@type='TypeA']" frage.xml
on a file frage.xml with this content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
    <record type="TypeA">uqw8hY7V</record>
    <record type="TypeB">bN4mT0zL</record>
    <record type="TypeA">K6p4gJv2</record>
    <record type="TypeB">z8wQ9xV1</record>
    <record type="TypeA">a3rL7kY9</record>
    <record type="TypeB">m1W2pX4e</record>
    <record type="TypeA">y8T6r5zQ</record>
    <record type="TypeB">k9pJ2wT3</record>
    <record type="TypeA">d7V1gL5b</record>
    <record type="TypeB">t4Y6n0pM</record>
</records>

outputs:
<record type="TypeA">uqw8hY7V</record><record type="TypeA">K6p4gJv2</record><record type="TypeA">a3rL7kY9</record><record type="TypeA">y8T6r5zQ</record><record type="TypeA">d7V1gL5b</record>

while I would appreciate some NL there, my problem is, that there is no root node, which makes it uncomfortable to work with the output, because the software I want to use requires valid XML.
Is there a way to make xmlstarlet putting a root node for the output?

Maybe you should be removing instead of selecting? e.g.:
xmlstarlet ed -d '//record[@type != "TypeA"]' frage.xml

Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <record type="TypeA">uqw8hY7V</record>
  <record type="TypeA">K6p4gJv2</record>
  <record type="TypeA">a3rL7kY9</record>
  <record type="TypeA">y8T6r5zQ</record>
  <record type="TypeA">d7V1gL5b</record>
</records>


An alternative is: xmlstarlet sel -t -e records -c "//record[@type='TypeA']" frage.xml | xmlstarlet fo

@Luuk: nice. you should probably post that as an answer

I have done that just now, but this is better (I think)

I love both answers! But the delete solution is more resource efficient, so I upvoted both and accept this one

An alternative is:
xmlstarlet sel -t -e records -c "//record[@type='TypeA']" frage.xml | xmlstarlet fo

The xmlstarlet fo is just needed for the, optional, formatting.
